# Associations in seed.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have following models in my app

```
class Building < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :rooms, dependent: :destroy
  ...

class Room < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :building
  has_many :lessons, dependent: :destroy
  ...

class Lesson < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :course
  ...
```

Everything worked fine between Bulding and its rooms with this code:

```
if Building.find_by_code("PAR").nil?
   building = Building.create!({title: "Areál Parukářka", code: "PAR"})
    
   par_rooms.each do |room|
      building.rooms << Room.create({title: room[0], code: room[1]})
   end 
end
```

Now I want to add lessons to each Room. With the following code, no error is raised, and when I add some "puts" it says that the lessons has been created, but they are not available inside the controller/view. Here's the seed I use:

```
if Building.find_by_code("PAR").nil?
  building = Building.create!({title: "Areál Parukářka", code: "PAR"})

  par_rooms.each do |room|
    new_room = Room.create({title: room[0], code: room[1]})
    building.rooms << new_room
    lesson = Lesson.create({start_at: DateTime.new(2018, 11, 20, 8), end_at: DateTime.new(2018, 11, 20, 9, 30), duration: 45, room_id: new_room.id, teacher_id: nil, course_id: nil})
    new_room.lessons << lesson
  end
```

rooms and lessons tables has the following schema:

```
create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "code"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "building_id"
    t.index ["building_id"], name: "index_rooms_on_building_id"
  end


create_table "lessons", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "start_at"
    t.datetime "end_at"
    t.integer "duration"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "room_id"
    t.integer "teacher_id"
    t.integer "course_id"
    t.index ["course_id"], name: "index_lessons_on_course_id"
    t.index ["room_id"], name: "index_lessons_on_room_id"
    t.index ["teacher_id"], name: "index_lessons_on_teacher_id"
  end
```

Comment: Did you run the seeds ? `rails db:seed`

Comment: Yes I did that.

Comment: Can you replace `create` by `create!` in your seeds and run them again to see if there is an error

Comment: Theres an error raised "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Building must exist" but when I run the server and open the app, I can see that bulding

Comment: Also, theres "Building.destroy_all" at the beginning of the seed

Comment: replace this : `new_room = Room.create({title: room[0], code: room[1]})` with this : `new_room = Room.create({title: room[0], code: room[1], building: building})`

Comment: Tell me if it works so i can answer your question :)

Comment: It raises error "NameError: undefined local variable or method `room' for main:Object", did you want to add the building id for the room?

Comment: in which line do you have this error ?

Comment: On the line wheres the new Room is created, also when I run the app theres the building created but no Rooms in it.

Comment: how did you define `par_rooms`

Comment: I have added the schema of rooms table to the question and the par_rooms is an array.                                                                                                            par_rooms = [
  ["Kanárek", "PAR O.1"],
  ["Albrecht", "PAR 1.1"],
  ["Alfons", "PAR 1.2"],
  ["Abrahám", "PAR 1.3"],
  ["Gauč", "PAR 2.1"]
]

Comment: You may add the lesson schema as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lesson = Lesson.create({
    start_at: DateTime.new(2018, 11, 20, 8), 
    end_at: DateTime.new(2018, 11, 20, 9, 30), 
    duration: 45, room_id: new_room.id, 
    teacher_id: nil,     # is problematic with your model
    course_id: nil})     # is problematic with your model
```

Your model suggests that all relations are needed.

You should, if there are empty relations given, mark

```
belongs_to :teacher, optional: true
```

as optional.

Not that this solves your problem, but it should be the right direction.

For more ideas you should provide the schemas for teacher, course, room and building.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. I've marked id's that doesn't exist in the moment when a lesson is created and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try `new_room = building.rooms.create({title: room[0], code: room[1]})` , and remove the line `building.rooms << new_room`